# How is it possible to upload photo directly from mobile phone/webcam and link it to an entry?

Tags: assets

I would like to take photos on a mobile phone/webcam and upload them automatically when the photo is taken. Currently, I'm taking photos have it saved on my local desktop and upload them manually to my Craft site as asset. Just wondering if there's a way to upload directly from mobile phone/webcam without uploading it manually?

Answer (score 1):

You would likely need to make a new field type, and extend Craft's codebase via module to allow it to take a photo instead of uploading.

Currently (at time of answering) there are no plugins that facilitate this for v3 or v4 of Craft CMS.

Here's a generic web answer, if you choose to proceed with a custom bit of functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241707/using-form-input-to-access-camera-and-immediately-upload-photos-using-web-app

Information on writing modules is available here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/module-guide.html